# Enviar Uma Mensagem Usando javaScript

Tags: javascript

Como faço para enviar mensagem automática em um certo 'chat' de um site, sendo que não tem nenhum botão que faça o envio, o código teria que ser em JavaScript (lembrando que não é formulário, é um campo de mensagem apenas).

Comment: Para evitar informações divididas em mais de uma postagem, queiram utilizar o campo de comentários da [postagem original, neste link](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/555664/70) - mais instruções sobre o fechamento e possibilidade de reabertura lá.